# How can I find my lost iPhone 7 Plus?

Tags: iphone, sim

I lost my iPhone yesterday and I didn't turn on mobile data, so I couldn't use Find my iPhone to locate it. I have tried to call many times, but no one answers and the phone keeps ringing. That means my iPhone is still active with my SIM card. Does anybody know how can I locate my iPhone? (I use a Vodafone SIM card and I purchased my phone on plan.)

Comment: Is Find my iPhone activated at all?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can locate your device without it connecting to the internet. You can go to [this link](https://www.icloud.com/#find) and enable the lost mode. I am not sure if your phone was locked, if it was then there's no way it can have internet unless it is unlocked. If it was not locked and it gets internet access then the lost mode will be enabled and you can get the phones location. Also the phone will be locked after that.

Once you enable Lost Mode, you will also get an option to enable 'Notify me when found', enable that option as well.

If your have not enabled Two-factor authentication for Apple ID and if you have any other apple device then I suggest you enable it by following instructions on [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204915). Because now there are high chances of someone trying to hack your apple id to use the phone.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the find my iPhone app? Just sign in with iCloud and your phone will start making a noise

Comment: Well, OP doesn't have mobile data on, so that wasn't an option.